# How can I plot NDVI time series from multiple polygon into one graph with a single line instead of one line each polygon?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series

I want to plot NDVI time series from multiple polygon into one graph with a single line instead of one line for each polygon.

Here's part of my code:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var TanzaniaBoundary = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na','Tanzania'));

// Create image collection of S-2 imagery for the perdiod 2020
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

//filter start and end date
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')

//filter cloud cover
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))


//filter according to drawn boundary
.filterBounds(TanzaniaBoundary);


//Map.addLayer(S2,{bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min:0, max: 3000}, 'True colour image');
Map.addLayer(table, {color: 'red'}, 'cassava point');

// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
};

// Add NDVI band to image collection
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);
// Extract NDVI band and create NDVI median composite image
var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median(); //I just changed the name of this variable ;)

// Create palettes for display of NDVI
var ndvi_pal = ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b',
'#a6d96a'];

// Create a time series chart.
var plotNDVI1 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(S2,North,ee.Reducer.mean(),
'nd',500,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'NDVI short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});

// Display.
print(plotNDVI1);

// Display NDVI results on map
Map.addLayer(NDVImed.clip(North), {min:-0.5, max:0.9, palette: ndvi_pal}, 'NDVI')
```

and complete in following link:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/33153e20a937e5a7b5360bb0696bfa4b

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the table so the code will work,

I made an app that create NDVI chart for polygon/s

https://harelg25.users.earthengine.app/view/ndvi-chart

I can share the code if this what you looking for